# inserting a line break in a comment

Tags: support, comments

Is this possible? It gets annoying when I want to address two different things in one comment (or two different people) and it all gets crammed together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not currently supported. The best workaround would be to just add two comments.

Comment: Is there a reason why this is not supported, or did they not get around to it yet?

Comment: More info here on MSO: [Why can you type new lines in comments if they are never rendered?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63303/why-can-you-type-new-lines-in-comments-if-they-are-never-rendered)

Comment: It seems that you can have newlines in comments render????

Comment: @soandos: no. In fact, you have to go out of your way to even *get* newlines in a comment. If you have something that needs newlines to be readable, consider putting it into an answer...