# Why do line breaks not work for me in comments?

Tags: support, status-bydesign

The help text recommends insertion of a double space when a line break is required.  It don't work for me.

The answer [here](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/3086/inserting-a-line-break-in-a-comment) is not helpful.

Comment: The answer you link to simply states it is not possible. As far as I know this has not changed, I have ever seen a line break in comments.

Comment: line breaks are not supported in comments.

Comment: Its not just for you. Comments don't get as much love ;p

Comment: So why the deceptive help text?

Comment: @Pablo678 You're reading the wrong help section. When adding a comment, you get [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/V2Qr8.png) explanation, linking to [this section of the formatting help](http://superuser.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) which starts with the following statement: *Comments support only bold, italic, code and links; in addition, a few shorthand links are available.*. Nothing deceptive about it.

Answer (score 3):

Comments use [a subset of Markdown](https://superuser.com/editing-help#comment-formatting). Linebreaks are not supported.